# How to call one line at a time in LabVIEW read text file?

Tags: labview

I would like to read just one line of text at a time using "Read from text file" function. After the passing of this line I would like to move on to the next line after the rest of the program iterates once. When I change the "Read from text file" function to "Read lines", I can no longer put an indicator on the front panel for text. How can I iterate one line at a time? How can I put an indicator on the front panel to display which line of text was read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you want:

1. `Open/Create/Replace File` (with inputs `open` and `read-only`)
   — inside `While Loop`:
2. `Read From Text File` (with Read Lines)
3. End `While Loop` on error from `Read From Text File`
   --After `While Loop`:
4. `Close File`

You can process the data in the While loop, or index it and process outside.

[image: Process text file one line at a time]

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the Text file
2. Use for loop, and add the shift register to it
3. Through the input shift register terminal, wire the text file output (Initial data)
4. In Front panel, **Right Click >> String >> Additional String Function >> Search/Split String**
5. Wire the Initial data (from shift register) to the input string terminal and Provide the necessary search string/ Character (In my case, I have used line feed constant)
6. Search/Split String has two output terminals; Substring before the match and match +rest of the String
7. Trime the whitespace and wire the **match +rest of the String o/p to the o/p shift register**; Take the desired o/p from **Substring before the match** terminal
8. Set the tunnel mode of the desired string as indexing so that each line in the file is indexed to an element in the array.

**Note:** N value of the for loop's iteration terminal is equal to the no of lines in the file.

[image: Image for Reference]